# Next.js build failed

Tags: node.js, next.js

I tried to build Next.js but I am getting the following error message

node version 16.13.2

npm version 8.5.5

ubuntu version  20

next.js version 12.1.0

```
info  - Loaded env from /opt/4cash-wallet-1/admin/client/.env.production
warn  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-minify-enabled
info  - Checking validity of types
/usr/bin/node[744828]: ../src/node_platform.cc:61:std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start(): Assertion `(0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))' failed.
 1: 0xb00e10 node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0xb00e8e  [/usr/bin/node]
 3: 0xb7045e  [/usr/bin/node]
 4: 0xb70526 node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*) [/usr/bin/node]
 5: 0xac43f9 node::InitializeOncePerProcess(int, char**, node::InitializationSettingsFlags) [/usr/bin/node]
 6: 0xac4696 node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/bin/node]
 7: 0x7f007a60d0b3 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 8: 0xa3bf3c  [/usr/bin/node]
/usr/bin/node[744828]: ../src/node_platform.cc:61:std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start(): Assertion `(0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))' failed.
```

Comment: try this => delete `node_modules`, `.next` folders `yarn.lock` file, then run `yarn install` command and then `yarn build`